# Normalising values in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was looking to normalise data and came across two different methods. Here is the first one:

```
normed = prices / prices.ix[0, :]
```

and another which made direct sense to me:

```
normed = prices.values / prices.sum()
```

What is the difference between the two methods?  In the second method, we are dividing all values in an array with the sum of values in array. But what is happening in the first method?

Comment: In the first block of code, it's working with a 2D object. In the second, it's likely a 1D array

Comment: @roganjosh Where does it sum in the first example?

Comment: `ix` is deprecated. Try `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}); print(df.iloc[0, :])` and you'll see the 2D indexing in action

Comment: @roganjosh Can you answer with an example? Currently, it is not making any sense to me

Comment: That was an example but it's a bit of a leap to go for an answer because I don't know the source of your info. Try `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}); print(df.iloc[1, :])` in addition to my initial example. Also `print(df)` on its own; you should see the pattern. You're indexing by `[row, column]`, and `:` just says "all the values in that dimension"

Comment: @roganjosh How does this normalise ?

Comment: Ah, I think I've misinterpreted your confusion. No, it doesn't normalise on its own, you're right